# Redis Server multiple clusters on same hosts

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

We have Redis Server cluster. Can we use multiple Redis clusters on the same hosts?

Comment: I don't see why not, you just need to configure your clusters correctly with the correct configuration and make sure your ports don't overlap between the two clusters. I would try it out with the cluster tutorial: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial can test it on your local computer.

Comment: is there any information in official documentation about 2 clusters on a same hosts?

Comment: Not really... What bothers you/missing info?

Comment: Yeah the official documentation doesn't describe 2 clusters on same host but I would just set up your first cluster and then set up the second cluster making sure all the ports are on a different set of ports and theoretically it should work. The set up process specifically specify which instances talk to what for set up so it doesn't do any magically discovery which may prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you should be able to do this following the steps found here in Pivotal's knowledge base:

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/206087627-How-to-setup-and-run-multiple-Redis-server-instances-on-a-Linux-host

Note that these instructions assume that you have Redis already installed on the machine (default port 6379), and walks you through installing another.

Assuming that you want the port for your second instance to be 6380:

1) Copy your configs:

```
cp /etc/redis/redis_6379.conf /etc/redis/redis_6380.conf
```

2) Edit `/etc/redis/redis_6380.conf` and put the new port in the following lines:

```
pidfile /var/run/redis_6380.pid
port 6380
logfile /var/log/redis/redis_6380.log
dir /var/lib/redis/6380
```

3) Make sure it has a new working directory (matching the `dir` line above):

```
mkdir /var/lib/redis/6380
```

4) Edit `/etc/init.d/redis_6379` and change these lines:

```
NAME=`basename ${0}`
PIDFILE=/var/run/${NAME}.pid
CONF="/etc/redis/${NAME}.conf"
REDISPORT="${NAME#*_}"
```

5) Create a symlink for the second instance:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/redis_6379 /etc/init.d/redis_6380
```

6) Start the new instance:

```
/etc/init.d/redis_6380 start
```

7) Make sure it is running:

```
/usr/local/redis/src/redis-cli -p 6380 -a redisPassword info server
```

You should get similar results by running that command for port 6379.

Comment: This is for two redis instances, not two redis clusters. But I assume configuration will be similar to making sure you set up the instances separately and then running to configure which instances talk to which ones for clustering.